# TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="descriptive-slogan"]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have written two tests in homePage.test.js file for testing my Home Page component. I'm using data-testid to get the dom node. Both the data-testid's are present in my dom. When I run tests first test runs successfully but the second one shows the above-mentioned error.

**homePage.test.js**

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import Home from "../src/pages/index"


render(<Home />)
test("main slogan", () => {
    const text = /^Create Beautiful Coversfor blogs like a pro/
    expect(screen.getByTestId('main-slogan')).toHaveTextContent(text);
})

test("descriptive slogan", () => {

    const text = /^We at Cover Builders are aimed to provide you simple and easy tools, that helps you in generating blog covers easily/
    expect(screen.getByTestId("descriptive-slogan")).toHaveTextContent(text);
})
```

**Home Page component**

```js
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import Image from "next/image";
import editorGif from "../../public/editorGif.gif"


export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Box className="homepage-gradient" sx={{ gridColumnStart: '1', gridColumnEnd: '4', color: 'white' }}>
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', padding: '6rem 4rem', width: '100%', height: '100%', gap: 4 }}>
        <Box sx={{ width: '60%', }}>
          <Typography data-testid="main-slogan" sx={{ fontSize: '3rem', fontWeight: 'fontWeightBold' }}>
            Create Beautiful Covers<br />
            for blogs like a pro
          </Typography>
          <Typography data-testid="descriptive-slogan" sx={{ padding: '2rem 0', fontSize: '1.2rem' }}>
            We at Cover Builders are aimed to provide you simple and easy tools,<br />
            that helps you in generating blog covers easily.
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ width: '40%', }}>
          <Image
            src={editorGif}
            alt="full_editor"
            style={{ borderRadius: '10px', margin: '0 0 0 2rem', }}
          >

          </Image>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your test file accordingly,
If you are still in confusion, I have put your test file here,
I ran it and it worked.
https://github.com/YamatoDX/testing-practice-next/blob/testing/__tests__/Stack.test.tsx

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom' // may be you don't need to import this
import Home from "../src/pages/index"

test("main slogan", () => {
  render(<Home />);
  const text = /^Create Beautiful Coversfor blogs like a pro/;
  expect(screen.getByTestId("main-slogan")).toHaveTextContent(text);
});

test("descriptive slogan", () => {
  render(<Home />);
  const text =
    /^We at Cover Builders are aimed to provide you simple and easy tools,that helps you in generating blog covers easily./i;
  expect(screen.getByTestId("descriptive-slogan")).toHaveTextContent(text);
});
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer but can you tell me the reason why I have to separately render Home compoent in each test ?

Comment: const text =
    /^We at Cover Builders are aimed to provide you simple and easy tools, that helps you in generating blog covers easily./i;
There is a space after comma in ur test file in this text, but in the component there wasn't.

Comment: actually that is a problem I know I resolved it  but that's not my query.

Comment: I'm asking about Home component which I have defined at top of my file but you have rendered it in each test

Comment: oh, usually I always rendered the component under each test block, otherwise it always threw me error. Deep down reason that I dn know yet.